# DOMDocument DOMXpath store attributes like unique ids in php

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I want to detect differences in dom structures and compare nodes. Therefore I set a special object attribute "uniqid" to every DOMElement / DOMText object.

This works:

```php
<?php
class _1
{
    public $DOMDocument = null;
    public $DOMXpath = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->DOMDocument = new \DOMDocument();
        $this->DOMDocument->loadHTML('<div>foo</div>');
        $this->DOMXpath = new \DOMXpath($this->DOMDocument);
        $nodes = $this->DOMXpath->query('/html/body//node()');
        $nodes_id = 1;
        foreach ($nodes as $nodes__value) {
            $nodes__value->uniqid = $nodes_id;
            $nodes_id++;
        }
        var_dump(@$this->DOMXpath->query('/html/body//text()')[0]->uniqid);
    }
}

$_1 = new _1();
// 2
```

Now I just moved the logic in separate functions:

```php
<?php
class _2
{
    public $DOMDocument = null;
    public $DOMXpath = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->DOMDocument = new \DOMDocument();
        $this->DOMDocument->loadHTML('<div>foo</div>');
        $this->DOMXpath = new \DOMXpath($this->DOMDocument);
        $this->test1();
        $this->test2();
    }
    public function test1()
    {
        $nodes = $this->DOMXpath->query('/html/body//node()');
        $nodes_id = 1;
        foreach ($nodes as $nodes__value) {
            $nodes__value->uniqid = $nodes_id;
            $nodes_id++;
        }
    }
    public function test2()
    {
        var_dump(@$this->DOMXpath->query('/html/body//text()')[0]->uniqid);
    }
}

$_2 = new _2();
// NULL
```

- Can somebody explain why _1 is working and _2 is not?
- How can I safely "store" attributes (not dom attributes) to DOMDocument / DOMText objects for later access?

Comment: I believe that `$this->DOMXpath->query('/html/body//text()')` will return new instance of results with "original" references to objects (without your unique ID) ALSO because you are not writing back to DOM changes you have made you are basically querying original DOM again

Comment: Thanks. This does not explain it in full detail, but I do it now with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

I do have now another approach for receiving an unique "id" for any node element:

```php
$node->getNodePath()
```

It's as simple as that. It works for DOMText and DOMElement objects.